# Can I send output from nohup to multiple files?

Tags: nohup

I would like to be able to send the output from nohup to more than one file. Does anybody have any thoughts on this? I cannot find anything about this anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tee command for that purpose,

```
nohup <your-command> | tee -a file1 file2 &
```

And, to stop you standard output from showing in console, you can redirect it as follows,

```
nohup <your-command> | tee -a file1 file2 > /dev/null &
```

Hope it helps.

Also correct me if i am wrong or, there is any better way to do it.